# Are these instructions for installing a range hood code compliant?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, code-compliance, appliances, hood

I'm looking at installing an island-mount range hood. I've seen a few that come with a plug, rather than requiring hard-wiring. Where am I supposed to plug this thing in? Well, I finally found one that answers the question. (Sort of. That hanging sentence shown below never gets concluded.)

[image]

Now, installing an electrical outlet inside my ceiling like this *can't* be code-compliant. It's not accessible! It seems like my only options are to land my building wiring directly in the range hood, or to cut the plug off and land both the building wiring and the plug-less cable in an accessible junction box in my ceiling. Am I missing something that makes this okay?

Comment: Plug-in receptacles always need to be accessible. That would only be the case in the ceiling if it were an attic. The normal installation is hardwired. **Make/model # of this hood?**

Comment: Do you have an attic above?

Comment: No attic, it's below a second floor bedroom.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference in the code regarding "readily accessible" and " permanently accessible" .  "readily" applies to switches and esp outlets.  "Permanently" means the connections or outlets need to be accessible without resorting to tearing out insulation, sheet rock, other walling, etc.

Comment: What if the outlet is accessible by removing the hood duct cover(s)?

Comment: @Huesmann  Not sure on that one, but I would think it would qualify as accessible because you're not burying it in something that needs to be destroyed and repaired, just remove a cover. Admittedly, to me this is a gray area.

Comment: Right, like behind an access panel is obviously OK, but how much stuff do you need to have to move before it becomes not OK?